# Laravel3: How can I forward post methods to action of controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

```
Route::get('admin/user/add', function()
{
    if (!Input::has('submit'))
        return View::make('theme-admin.user_add');
    else
        Redirect::to('admin@user_add_process');
});
```

Normal `GET request` to `admin/user/add` shows the register form. However, when the form is submitted, I have to redirect it to `action_user_add_process()` function of `Admin controller` so I can save values to database.

The solution above doesn't work and I get 404's.

I call form action like this:

```
action="{{ URL::to('admin/user/add') }}">
```

How can I solve this issue?

Ps. If there is a shorter way to achieve this, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you are redirecting to a controller action using the `to_action()` method of Redirect.

```
return Redirect::to_action('admin@user_add_process');
```

Alternatively, you could just use this URL that doesnt even use the route you created making the if/else irrelevant.

```
{{ URL::to_action('admin@user_add_process') }}
```

On a third note, keeping your routes clean makes maintainence alot easier moving forward. As routes use a restful approach, take advantage of it. Using the same URL you can create and return the View with a GET request and submit forms with a POST request.

```
Route::get('admin/user/add', function() { ... }

Route::post('admin/user/add', function() { ... }
```

You can also have your routes automatically use a controller action like this:

```
Route::post('admin/user/add', 'admin@user_add_process');
```

Comment: Just what I did before your reply. Thanks anyway!